# last digit is a square and.....

Tags: number-theory

I've found some solutions for this questions but they were not impressive.

**Question**:

How many natural numbers are there in base $10$,whose last digit is perfect square,combination of last two digits is a perfect square,combination of last three digits is a perfect square,$\ldots$,combination of last $n$ digits is a perfect square?

For example $64$ is a number whose last digit is a perfect square and combination of last two digits is also a perfect square.

Kindly tell me how to approach this question.

Comment: There are infinitely many such numbers. Here are some of them: $10^2,10^4,10^6,\dots$

Comment: Try to write on a piece of paper some perfect squares, select those satisfying this property and look for a pattern.

Comment: I've done the same as suggested by crostul when I left the cases of number having only 0 & 1 as their digits.

Comment: Your question starts with "How many natural numbers are there..." - well, there are infinitely many. What more do you want?

Comment: I want other than those numbers you have suggested, please,,,,

Comment: @AtulMishra You should rule out a $0$ at the end to make the problem more interesting

Comment: OK, so here are some more: $49\cdot10^2,49\cdot10^4,49\cdot10^6,\dots$

Comment: And some more: $64\cdot10^2,64\cdot10^4,64\cdot10^6,\dots$

Comment: And some more: $81\cdot10^2,81\cdot10^4,81\cdot10^6,\dots$

Comment: And some more: $4\cdot10^2,4\cdot10^4,4\cdot10^6,\dots$

Comment: And some more: $9\cdot10^2,9\cdot10^4,9\cdot10^6,\dots$

Comment: Yes, those in the last two comments are also $3$-digit numbers (and generally, consist of an odd number of digits).

Comment: In order to make your question "worthwhile", you should add '**$n$-digit**' immediately after '**How many**'.

Comment: @barakmanos The problem gets more interesting if we rule out trailing zeros. I didn't verify it yet, but then, there should be only finite many numbers.

Comment: Interestingly, for the  case up to two-digit numbers: $\overline{a(b^2)}=10a+b^2=(a+b)^2$ and $10=a+2b$ $$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & 8 & 6 & 4 \\
\hline
b & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
a+b & 9 & 8 & 7 \\
\hline
10a+b^2 & 81 & 64 & 49 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers are in the forms:-

(i)$4\times10^n$

(ii)$9\times10^n$

(iii)$10^n$

(iv)$49\times10^n$

(v)$64\times10^n$

(vi)$81\times10^n$

Where $n \in 0,2,4,6...$

Comment: I beg your pardon?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean (and you're wrong).

Comment: But I think these are the only possible solutions

Comment: What about $900$?

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: 900=9*10^2 @Henrik

Comment: while $90=9 \times 10$ is not a perfect square

Comment: see to what n belongs to

Comment: $90$ is not the "last two digits" of any of the given numbers, and given that the OP gave $64$ as a vald example, it's not even unclear what end to start at when determining what is the last digit.

Comment: And yes, it's correct now.

Comment: Oh! thanks to you

Comment: 0 is also a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let us start without accepting trailing zeroes.

And let us then start by looking at last (least significant) digits.

As the last digit has to be a perfect square, it has to be $1$, $4$ or $9$.

Going to two digits, the above criterion, limits the number of candidates to $9\cdot 3 = 27$. Comparing those to a list of perfect sqaures, gives three numbers: $49$, $64$ and $81$.

If we go to three digits we again only have $27$ candidates, none of which are perfect squares.

So without trailing zeroes, there are six such numbers.

As $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$, it's clear that multiplying any two squares we get another square, and since multiplying by $10^n$ just adds $n$ zeroes to a number, we can multiply each of those six numbers by $10^{2n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$. Giving us all the solutions to the problem.